# Make cmd the meta key in emacs running in iTerm

Tags: emacs

I run Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavricks) and use EmacsMac installed via macports package emacs-app-mac (emacs version 24.3.1). The GUI uses cmd as the meta key, which is what I want. But I also run   the same binary (emacs points to Emacs -nw) in my iTerm2 terminal (Build 1.0.0.20131116), where meta-key is alt instead of cmd.

In iTerm preferences i've tried the different settings for "left option key acts as ..." but no joy there. Is there a way I can get emacs in iTerm to recognise cmd as my meta key?

Comment: I remember having this option in Apple's Terminal.app, but like you I don't see it in iTerm2. As a hack you might have success with remapping it with [KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).

Answer (score 5):

Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys has what you want.

Mine is set to +Esc. I know, meta looks like what you want but it is not it.

Comment: Thanks, this works with one additional step: In Preferences --> Keys set "Left command key = Left Option" (that way right cmd key still usable for flipping tabs, etc.)